# A single keyboard shortcut to toggle between different shortcuts

Tags: keyboard

I'll start from my end goal so it will be clearer - I have a mouse with buttons that can be assigned to output keyboard shortcuts. I'm using [Divvy](https://mizage.com/divvy/) and I want to use it so that whenever I click that button a different Divvy shortcut will be used. So for example:

- 1st click - Center window
- 2nd click - Align to the left
- 3rd click - Align to the right
- 4th click - Center
- 5th click - left .... and so on

What piece of software am I missing to map between what I'll use with the mouse and the cyclic shortcuts to be used with Divvy?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to achieve this. Although you might have to write a small script to achieve this kind of functionality. There are a lot of great guides on how to use Karabiner and the doc section on the website is also a pretty good place to start.